# Heroku throwing Error H14 No web process running while trying to deploy flask app even after correct Procfile and scale web=1 not working

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, flask, heroku

The Procfile is defined as below:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --workers 1 --worker-class=gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --timeout 600
```

and the logs from Heroku are:

```
2022-03-10T09:04:35.223306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=emotion-sys.herokuapp.com request_id=0f9c469f-1bdb-422c-8bc7-62396368bc40 fwd="103.75.160.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2022-03-10T09:04:35.616871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=emotion-sys.herokuapp.com request_id=58755a0c-46fd-42fe-8cda-66bd9a4c46d0 fwd="103.75.160.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The problems still persistes after executing heroku ps:scale web=1 and enabling free dyno from heroku. The port is given as 8080 and wsgi server is usede for production.

Application Logs:

```
2022-03-19T08:43:22.656492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-19T08:43:22.723787+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-25T11:23:32.487590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=emotion-sys.herokuapp.com request_id=6f5a63ad-c2af-4b8b-8979-e8ef7d0398e7 fwd="103.77.137.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-25T11:23:38.293173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=emotion-sys.herokuapp.com request_id=b5d73851-0f14-43a8-b215-c3c8e7684c86 fwd="103.77.137.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Most of the previous stackoverflow answers have been implemented but still unable to solve the issue.

And my github repo link is here: https://github.com/souloper/FaceEmotionDetecion

*Pardon me if this looks so unprofessional. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: "No web processes running" generally means you need to scale your `web` process up. Are you _entirely sure_ you have done this successfully? If you run `heroku ps:scale web=1` again, what happens?

Comment: "The port is given as 8080"—no it isn't. If you're seeing port 8080 being used it's because of a misconfiguration in your code, not because Heroku asked you to use that port.